# How to make firefox from snapcraft access home directory?

Tags: firefox, snap

I've just installed firefox with

```
snap install firefox
```

but I can't open/save anything on the home directory.

I tried

```
sudo snap connect firefox:home :home
```

and it didn't work. I click open and it does nothing. Also saving a page does nothing.

Other softwares, like Inkscape, will only run if I launch with root;

```
 snap run inkscape
error: cannot find current revision for snap inkscape: readlink /snap/inkscape/current: permission denied
```

which is not nice

Answer (score 0):

Strange, I have an issue only with saving the files (on Kubuntu).

To fix this I have tried to install Firefox with `--devmode` and `--classic` flags to remove the snap security confinement.
I have tried also to use /media directory as a target after connecting it with `sudo snap connect firefox:removable-media`.

All the above didn't help, but I have paid attention that retrying the download makes the job, i.e. clicking the retry icon in the download manager window.